# How to show message when there is no comment in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to show a message to the user when the post doesn't have any comments...

so I have a map like this

```
  {comments.length === 0 ? (
          comments.map((comment, key) => {
          // codes here......
      );
          })
        ) : (
          <>
            <h2>There is no comment yet...</h2>
          </>
        )}
```

here I am checking if there are no comments by comments.length but it is showing the message when there is a comment and hides the comment instate, but when there is no comment, it doesn't show the message.

any suggestions?

Comment: How can `comments.length` be less than zero?

Comment: hhahha, yes sorry for that it was === 0

Comment: Now you are mapping comments if there are none, and showing "There is no comment yet" if there are comments. Wrong way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{comments.length > 0 ? () : () }
```

OR

```
{comments.length !== 0 ? () : () }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check only variable comments if a variable is undefined until comment is set.

```
  {comments ? comments.map((comment, key) => ) :  <h2>There is no comment yet...</h2>}
```

If a variable comments is initialized you can do:

```
{comments != null || comments.length != 0 ? comments.map((comment, key) => ) :  <h2>There is no comment yet...</h2>}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! your answer is completely right. it solved the problem with the @chandan-02 answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you sent can't even be run because of syntax error. by the way it should be written like this:

```
{comments.length === 0 ? (
    <>
        <h2>There is no comment yet...</h2>
    </>
) : (
    comments.map((comment, key) => {
        // codes here......
    })
)}
```

Comment: Yeah, yeah, it is a great idea, thanks